# Neo4j, match node with exactly one label

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have 2 type of nodes. The first type have the `:Schema` label. The second type have both `:Root` and `:Schema` labels. I want to write a cypher that will match only the first type (containing only the `:Schema` label).

I have tried this:

```
MATCH (s:Schema) return s;
```

Which return the two types. Also getting the second type is easy, you just use

```
MATCH (s:Schema:Root) return s;
```

**So, what's the proper cypher to match nodes with exactly the requested label?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
match (s:Schema)
WHERE Not s:Root
RETURN s
```

Answer (score 12):

You can check the length of the `LABELS()` collection (which is handy if you don't know which other labels to exclude, but only know you want a single label):

```
MATCH (s:Schema)
WHERE LENGTH(LABELS(s)) = 1
return s;
```

Comment: **2022 Update**: In case you want to use this solution, you need to replace the function `LENGTH` with the `SIZE` one (i.e. `WHERE SIZE(LABELS(s)) = 1`), basically because `LENGTH` is now used to count the length of a path, meanwhile `SIZE` counts the elements in a list